# Characteristics of $f(x,y)=\sqrt{xy}$

Tags: real-analysis, definition

$f(x,y)=\sqrt{xy}$

(i) Determine the maximal domain of $f$, thus that the range is real.

(ii) Is $f$ continuous its domain?

(iii) Determine and describe all Level sets of $f$

To (i) $D:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:xy\geq0\}$

To (ii) $f$ is as a composition of continuous functions continuous everywhere on its domain.

To (iii) $\sqrt{xy} = c \Leftrightarrow xy=c^2 \Leftrightarrow y = \frac{c^2}{x}, x \neq 0$

Consider $x=0: \sqrt{0y}=c \Rightarrow c=0$

This seems very simple to me, but i can't see any mistakes. Is my solution correct?

Comment: i) and ii) are ok, but in iii) I arrive at $y=\frac{c^2}{x}$ for $c>0$ and $x\neq 0$. It remains to discuss the case $c<0$.

Comment: @Avitus It is $c\ge 0$ in any case.

Comment: @mfl right; but I would specify it

Answer (score 4):

i) You should specify that much more meaningfully. What parts of the plane is that?

ii) Be explicit: composition of what continuous functions?

iii) No, check your algebra and check your relation in different parts of the plane you identify in part i.

Comment: (i) $D:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:xy\geq0\}\Leftrightarrow \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:(x \land y > 0) \lor (x \land y <0) \} \lor (x \lor y = 0)\}$                                               (ii) composition of $xy$ and square root function